# fetch data from mysql to a list view in android only show the first item from the table how to fix?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, android-listview

i have android application that use connection between android and mysql database using php.
after fetching the mysql database i need to display the result in android listview.
but the problem is that the listview only display the first item in the table, but the result return form fetching the table in php show the hole data.

how to fix this problem can anyone help me ??

## logCat

```
   04-1205: 40: 32.901: D/AllUsers: (1254): {
    "message": "DISPLAYED Success",
    "userlist": [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "user": "user2"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "user": "michel"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "user": "georges"
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "user": "testtest1"
        }
    ],
    "success": 1
}
```

**the list view just show the first item:

 - "id": "2",
 - "user": "user2"**

## display_user.php

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will list all the emp
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();


    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all emp from emp table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM users") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {


    // looping through all results
    // emp node
    $response["userlist"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        // temp user array
            $userlist = array();
            $userlist["id"] = $row["id"];
            $userlist["user"] = $row["user"];



        // push single Employee into final response array
        array_push($response["userlist"], $userlist);
    }
    // success

    $response["message"] = "DISPLAYED Success";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no emp found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No User found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

## JSONParser.java

```
package com.devleb.loginDemo;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();

            Log.i("TagCovertS", "["+json+"]");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

## UserListActivity.java

```
package com.devleb.loginDemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UserListActivity extends ListActivity {

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> usersList;

    private static String url_display_user = "http://10.0.3.2/android_connect/display_user.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";


    private static final String TAG_USERS = "userlist";

    private static final String TAG_USER = "user";

    //private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

    // employees JSONArray
    JSONArray users = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_list);

        usersList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        new getUserList().execute();

        // getListView
        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

            //  String id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.uid)).getText()
            //          .toString();

                // Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), StatusList.class);
                // in.putExtra(TAG_ID, uid);

                // startActivity(in);
            }
        });
    }

    class getUserList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            UserListActivity.this.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> parametres = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_display_user,
                    "GET", parametres);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Users: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    users = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USERS);

                    // looping through All Users
                    for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = users.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String user = c.getString(TAG_USER);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_USER, user);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        usersList.add(map);

                        return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                    }
                } else {

                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            if (result != null) {

                UserListActivity.this
                        .setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                // updating UI from Background Thread
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        /**
                         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                         * */
                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                UserListActivity.this, usersList,
                                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_ID,
                                        TAG_USER }, new int[] { R.id.uid,
                                        R.id.name });
                        // updating listview
                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                });

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.user_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

## activity_user_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/background_1">
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

## list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/uid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: check size of `usersList` in onPostExecute. (note) don't need `runOnUiThread` in `onPostExecute`, this method run in `UIthread` on default,

Comment: i am checking about the size in the InBckground method ()           // looping through All Users
     **for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject c = users.getJSONObject(i);

      // Storing each json item in variable
      String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
      String user = c.getString(TAG_USER);

      // creating new HashMap
      HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

      // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
      map.put(TAG_ID, id);
      map.put(TAG_USER, user);

      // adding HashList to ArrayList
      usersList.add(map);**

Comment: @user3499032, try below code and let me know whether it is working or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is bellow code:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject c = users.getJSONObject(i);

          // Storing each json item in variable
          String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
          String user = c.getString(TAG_USER);

          // creating new HashMap
          HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

          // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
          map.put(TAG_ID, id);
          map.put(TAG_USER, user);

          // adding HashList to ArrayList
          usersList.add(map);

          return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
    }
```

you return `json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);` in `for` statement so `for` just loop for first position so you get fist line of your json, put out return from for statement

your code must be:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject c = users.getJSONObject(i);

          // Storing each json item in variable
          String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
          String user = c.getString(TAG_USER);

          // creating new HashMap
          HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

          // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
          map.put(TAG_ID, id);
          map.put(TAG_USER, user);

          // adding HashList to ArrayList
          usersList.add(map);

    }
    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);   <--- move this line after for statement
```

Comment: Ohhhh, my mistake, i didn't check that, Got your point, Thank you for redirecting me. +1 for your answer.

Comment: @shayan pourvatan thank you for your answer  this was the problem i did not see it

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this, Change yout **onPostExecute** mehod code like below.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,
                usersList);
mListView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
adapter.setNotifyOnChange(false);
mListView.invalidateViews();
```

where `mListview` is your **ListView** Object just replace it's name with your **Listview** name.

Comment: as OP used `ListActivity` class so don't need `mListView`, problem is in `doInBackground`,